# Find element in 2D matrix where rows and columns are sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, vectors

Elements of a matrix are given in sorted rows and columns. I want to find the element in an optimized way.

First, I will get the last element of a row, which will determine if a number can exist in the current row. If the number I want to search for is greater than the last row's element, there is no point is searching in that row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;


int main()
{
    vector <vector<int>> arr
    {
        {10,20,30},
        {25,26,60},
        {38,47,50}
    };

    int target = 47; // just test

    int r, c;
    r = 0;

    bool found = false;

    for (r = 0; r < arr.size(); r++)
    {
        c = arr[0].size() - 1;

        while (arr[r][c] < target)//skip the row
        {
            r++;
        }

        while(arr[r][c] > target && arr[r][0] < target)
        {
            c--;

            if (c < 0)
                break;
        }

        if (arr[r][c] == target)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found)
    cout << r << " " << c;
    else
    {
        cout << "Not Found";
    }

    return 0;
}

//output : 2 1
```

Comment: Why don't you just use 2 `for` loops ?

Comment: @denis because I don't need to. Column index needs to change at different time than row change.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the for loop to while.
Running a for loop and within it while loops.
Using a single while loop will do it, see the code below.

Also before checking this while loops check for the if that you are checking later on after while.

```
while (arr[r][c] < target)//skip the row
{
    r++;
}

while(arr[r][c] > target && arr[r][0] < target)
{
    c--;
    if (c < 0)
       break;
}
```

you should check for if search number is equal to this number in matrix before above while loops

```
if (arr[r][c] == target)
{
    found = true;
    break;
}
```

See below code.

```
//  n = the dimension matrix.
int i = 0, j = n-1;
while ( i < n && j >= 0 )
{
  if ( arr[i][j] == x )
  {
     cout<<"\n Element Found at " << i << ", " << j;
     break;
  }
  if ( arr[i][j] > x )
    j--;
  else //  if arr[i][j] < x
    i++;
}
cout<<"\n Element not found";
```

Time Complexity: O(n)

This approach will work for (m * n) matrix as well not only for (n * n) matrix.
Time Complexity in such case will be: O(m + n).